# Link QPushButton and QLineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit, qpushbutton

I work on Qt and I don't understand how to link `QPushButton` and `QLineEdit`. I did this for the `QPushButton` :

```
QHBoxLayout     accountlayout;
QLabel          accountlabel("AccountServer");
QLineEdit       accountlineedit;
QPushButton     accountbuttonselect("Select");
QPushButton     accountbuttonlaunch("Launch");
QPushButton     accountbuttonstop("Stop");
QString         accountfile;

accountlayout.addWidget(&accountlabel);
accountlayout.addWidget(&accountlineedit);
accountlayout.addWidget(&accountbuttonselect);
accountlayout.addWidget(&accountbuttonlaunch);
accountlayout.addWidget(&accountbuttonstop);
QObject::connect(&accountbuttonselect,
    &QPushButton::clicked,
    [&window, &accountfile] {
        accountfile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
            window,
            QObject::tr("Sélectionner un exécutable ..."),
            "C:/", QObject::tr("Exécutable (*.exe)"));
    });
layout.addLayout(&accountlayout);
```

I open `QFileDialog` to search for an executable file and I want to set the `QLineEdit` to show the directory specified. How can I do that?

Comment: Does my edit explain what you meant to ask for?

Comment: If that's the case, you need to create a `QFileDialog` yourself and use the `directory()` method instead of the convenience static method you're using right now.

Comment: ... are you simply missing a call to `accountlineedit.setText(accountfile)`?

Comment: @peppe, I tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: @Meugiwara , if what peppe suggested doesn't work, you need to provide more info, where do you have this snippet, is this in the main function? what happens exactly? how exactly doesn't it work? please try providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I use it just under the QObject::connect for the &accountbuttonselect

Comment: Please provide a *complete* `main.cpp` that reproduces the issue. See e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19011496/1329652) for inspiration.